# Docker container...-p 9944:9944 running Node Template not working on polkadot js apps

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template, substrate-front-end, docker

I'm trying to run a substrate node through docker container but i am not able to with this command:

`docker run -p 9944:9944 -p 30333:30333 -p 9933:9933 -p 9615:9615  docker.io/decentration/supersig-node:latest --dev --port 30333 --ws-port 9944 --rpc-port 9933`

The logs look like this:

```
2022-09-21 13:21:19 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9615    
2022-09-21 13:21:19 Running JSON-RPC HTTP server: addr=127.0.0.1:9933, allowed origins=None    
2022-09-21 13:21:19 Running JSON-RPC WS server: addr=127.0.0.1:9944, allowed origins=None
```

[image]

but i'm not getting any errors from the console.

What am i missing from the command?

*Update: i am allowing insecure messages but still not working from docker. Also i have a mac m2. I found that it can work on mac Intel chip. also if you add `--unsafe-ws-external` to the command then it should work fine.*

[image]

Comment: It only works in Firefox for me because of some policy. Are you using MacOS? Docker behaves a bit different there as well.

Comment: ok so the above command works for you on firefox, I will check that. Yes indeed im using MacOS. So its not necessarily an error in the command...

Comment: Try `--net=host` instead of the ports. It should only be used for local development and not deployment.

Comment: i tried `--net=host` replacing the -p ports, but then it attaches to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1, so i try to connect to ws://0.0.0.0:9944 and i get `...insecure access deprecated.`

Answer (score 2):

Try boot with:

```
--unsafe-ws-external --rpc-cors all
```

Comment: i tried this but then i try connect via ws://0.0.0.0:9944 instead of 127.0.0.1. And then the console error is `WS endpoint= ws://0.0.0.0:9944 The page at 'https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A9944#/addresses' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://0.0.0.0:9944/'. This endpoint should be available via WSS. Insecure access is deprecated.`
 + `...Connecting to a non-secure WebSocket server from a secure origin is deprecated.`

then i try wss:// and get: `API-WS: disconnected from wss://0.0.0.0:9944: 1006:: Abnormal Closure`

Comment: Yep, to solve that you just need to follow Guantong's answer.

Comment: my insecure content is already set to Allow. I wonder if the command is working for anyone, perhaps its my mac m2 on chrome with Docker, because it works fine without Docker.

Comment: From your screenshot, I think you are still in 'secure' mode.

Comment: that was an old screenshot, now insecure mode is allowed, and still same behaviour. i updated the main comment to show that.

Comment: Could you try `curl` your 9933 rpc port? And what about add `--network="host"` to your docker command or run with `127.0.0.1:9944:9944`?

Comment: i discovered its because of m1/m2 mac, which i forgot to mention. It works fine on Mac Intel, with the `--unsafe-ws-external` flag

Comment: You only need to do that in a different network ENV. I suggest you to check your docker network configurations. Is it use bridge or NAT or localhost?

Answer (score 2):

It seems we have found one of the problems could be. There is a problem for Mac M1/M2 chips related to port forwarding with Docker.

https://forums.docker.com/t/port-forward-not-working-on-a-macos-installation-but-works-on-others/77401/6

To guarantee it works, you need to run it over wss:// secure websocket connection, using reverse nginx proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried allowing Insecure content？Chrome allows you to connect to wss by default, but you are using ws. So you could try to allow `insecure content` for development

1. [image]
2. [image]

Comment: hey, i tried this but i think its a docker thing, because if i run a node-template outside of docker then it works fine.