# Can't access substrate node explorer

Tags: substrate-node-template, rpc, explorer

I expose RPC from the second node with command:

```
./target/release/node-template   \
--base-path /tmp/node02   \
--chain ./customSpecRaw.json   \
--listen-addr /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/30333   \
--ws-port 9946   \
--rpc-port 9934   \
--telemetry-url 'wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0'   \
--validator   \
--rpc-methods Unsafe   \
--name MyNode02   \
--bootnodes /ip4/<boot_node_ip>/tcp/30333/p2p/12xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx   \
--password-interactive \
--ws-external
```

I checked this socket port is running with telnet:

```
telnet 54.254.180.131 9946
```

But I got error **The operation is insecure** from explorer site: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F54.254.180.131%3A9946#/explorer

How I explore my node from polkadot.js?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried allowing Insecure content？Chrome allows you to connect to wss by default, but you are using ws. So you could try to allow insecure content for development. Also try Xavier's answer in another question https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/4933/1959
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. You right, it's working!